# How to filter the data in spark-shell using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop2

I have the below data which needed to be sorted using spark(scala) in such a way that, I only need id of the person who visited  "Walmart" but not "Bestbuy". store might be repetitive because a person can visit the store any number of times.

Input Data:

id, store

1, Walmart

1, Walmart

1, Bestbuy

2, Target

3, Walmart

4, Bestbuy

Output Expected:
3, Walmart

I have got the output using dataFrames and running SQL queries on spark context. But is there any way to do this using `groupByKey`/`reduceByKey` etc without dataFrames. Can someone help me with the code, After map-> `groupByKey`, a `ShuffleRDD` has been formed and I am facing difficulty in filtering the `CompactBuffer`!

**The code with which I got it using `sqlContext` is below:**

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD

case class Person(id: Int, store: String)

val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
               .map(_.split(","))
               .map(p => Person(p(1)trim.toInt, p(1)))
people.registerTempTable("people")

val result = sqlContext.sql("select id, store from people left semi join (select id from people where store in('Walmart','Bestbuy') group by id having count(distinct store)=1) sample on people.id=sample.id and people.url='Walmart'")
```

**The code which I am trying now is this, but I am struck after the third step:**

```
val data = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
             .map(x=> (x.split(",")(0),x.split(",")(1)))
             .filter(!_.filter("id"))
val dataGroup = data.groupByKey()
val dataFiltered = dataGroup.map{case (x,y) =>
    val url = y.flatMap(x=> x.split(",")).toList
    if (!url.contains("Bestbuy") && url.contains("Walmart")){
        x.map(x=> (x,y))}}
```

if I do dataFiltered.collect(), I am getting 
Array[Any] = Array(Vector((3,Walmart)), (), ())

Please help me how to extract the output after this step

Comment: would be easier if you show us the code you tried - a minimal, complete, verifiable example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TzachZohar: I have updated the code in the question, please have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: dataFiletered.collect().foreach(println)    gives me 


Vector((2,abc.com))
()
()

but I need only =>  3,Walmart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter an RDD, just use `RDD.filter`:

```
val dataGroup = data.groupByKey()

val dataFiltered = dataGroup.filter {
  // keep only lists that contain Walmart but do not contain Bestbuy:
  case (x, y) => val l = y.toList; l.contains("Walmart") && !l.contains("Bestbuy")
}

dataFiltered.foreach(println) // prints: (3,CompactBuffer(Walmart))

// if you want to flatten this back to tuples of (id, store):
val result = dataFiltered.flatMap { case (id, stores) => stores.map(store => (id, store)) }

result.foreach(println) // prints: (3, Walmart)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @TzachZohar, it worked perfectly. I unnecessarily have complicated things while filtering the RDD

Answer (score 0):

I also tried it another way and it worked out

```
val data = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
     .filter(!_.filter("id"))
         .map(x=> (x.split(",")(0),x.split(",")(1)))
data.cache()
val dataWalmart = data.filter{case (x,y) => y.contains("Walmart")}.distinct()
val dataBestbuy = data.filter{case (x,y) => y.contains("Bestbuy")}.distinct()
val result = dataWalmart.subtractByKey(dataBestbuy)
data.uncache()
```